# wget or curl executables not found. Curl activated but not working

Tags: drush

As I know so far Drush has some limitation on Windows. I need however, to get it working, and I have activated the curl module in php.ini. All you need is to uncomment the line:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Now, I run phpinfo.php and it seems curl is activated, but I still get the console error:

> wget or curl executables not found.

I have restarted the Apache server several times but still no way out.

Is anyone able to help me up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the php.exe path in drush.bat

The solution is to properly edit it. In my case ( I use xampp ) here is the path:

```
@echo off
REM See http://drupal.org/node/506448 for more information.
@c:\xampp\php\php.exe "%~dp0drush.php" %*
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're editing the correct php.ini file? Drush is a command line tool, and when PHP runs on the command line, it usually uses a different php.ini file than the PHP running under Apache (or any other web server).

To test if curl is enabled in command line PHP, run this command:

```
$ php -i | grep -A 3 'curl'
```

In my case (Ubuntu 11.04), the output was:

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,
--
curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.21.3
```

which means that curl is enabled.

To check which php.ini file your command line php uses, run:

```
$ php -i |grep php\.ini
```

In my case, the output was:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

On Windows, the values will be different but the idea is the same.

Comment: I found the solution: drush reads a bat file called drush.bat. It contains the path to php bin folder, in my case the default path was not the real one. I change it and voila! Here is the line that needs editing: @c:\xampp\php\php.exe "%~dp0drush.php" %*

Comment: Good to see you solved your problem. On Stackexchange, the 'right' way to add your solution to this page, is to add another answer. After 48 hours, you can even mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, but in case it helps somebody: I came here searching for a solution to the same error (`wget nor curl executables found.`), but the accepted answer did not work for me.

After a little more digging and testing, what turned out to be the cause of the problem is that the cygwin binaries folder had not been added to my windows environment path variable (System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables > System variable > Path).

In my case, the path to add was `C:\cygwin64\bin`. And now it works. :)

Answer (score -1):

Turn "allow_url_fopen" off in your php.ini file