# curl nor wget was found

Tags: drush

When I use drush to download modules, I get this weird error:

`drush dl registry_rebuild
exec(): Unable to fork [wget --version 2>&1] exec.inc:150 [warning]
exec(): Unable to fork [curl --version 2>&1] exec.inc:150 [warning]
exec(): Unable to fork [which curl 2>&1] exec.inc:150 [warning]
wget nor curl executables found. [error]`

which wget gives me /usr/bin/wget and which curl gives me /usr/bin/curl. /usr/bin/ is in my PATH. This seldom works if I do drush cc drush. How do I solve this permanently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [wget or curl executables not found. Curl activated but not working](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/wget-or-curl-executables-not-found-curl-activated-but-not-working)

Comment: That error in on windows. Besides, my error goes away temporarily if I do a `drush cc drush`

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: I am using CentOS.

Comment: I tried to download and enable facetapi, and I got the errors again. I cc'd all, then there were no problems.

Answer (score 1):

On Centos, to install wget:

```
sudo yum install wget
```

To install curl the following should suffice:

```
sudo yum install php-curl
sudo service httpd restart
```

++++++++++++++++++++ EDIT +++++++++++++++++++++++++

According to [this post](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/exec-unable-to-fork.22749/), "unable to fork" errors are likely to result from too many processes running.  They recommend increasing the limit like so:

```
sysctl -w kern.maxprocs=1000000
```

Comment: The op states that the commands are installed, this is tested by using 'which'.

Comment: well that's how you install them. :)  if it says they're installed, you should be able to use them. If you can't, it's possibly because the path hasn't been exported.

Comment: Right, I realize that's how they are installed, but that doesn't answer the question. It possibly is a path issue, but the op also states that the relevant directory _is_ in the `PATH` already.

Comment: oops, you're right. :s I've edited my answer to be more relevant.

Comment: `sysctl -w kern.maxprocs=1000000  
error: "kern.maxprocs" is an unknown key`

Answer (score 0):

On nginx on aws, I've found the php-fpm can get out of hand. To tell if that's happened, `ps -ef |grep php-fpm|wc -l`. If the number is more than 10 or so, you can reset php-fpm with: `sudo service php-fpm restart`

Answer (score 0):

I fix the "Unable to fork could" with Drush by restarting my server.
I think @Ollie's anwser is right.